# Arraylist.get returns hashcode instead of class's fields

Tags: java, polymorphism

I'm using Arraylist for 'heroes' - base class, and warrior,mage are derived classes. I want to return the lifePoints and attackPoints for each derived class by using the 'get' method, and instead I'm getting something like this (i believe it is the hashCode of the class).

**Note:** I've checked heroes.get(i) via debugging, it shows the right values, but I'm not sure as how to return them, so I thought about constructor without parameters - which fails.

**Output:**

```
Hero 0 is a Warrior@7852e922
Hero 1 is a Warrior@4e25154f
Hero 2 is a Magician@70dea4e
Hero 3 is a Magician@5c647e05
```

**Expected output:**

```
Hero 0 is a Warrier with -1 lifePoints and 5 attackPoints
Hero 1 is a Warrier with 5 lifePoints and 2 attackPoints
Hero 2 is a Magician with 12 lifePoints and 2 spellPoints
Hero 3 is a Magician with 13 lifePoints and 2 spellPoints
```

**My main class's semi-code**

```
for (int i=0; i<heroes.size(); ++i) {
System.out.println("Hero "+i+ " is a "+heroes.get(i));
}
```

**My thought process of the solution: using a constructor - fails.**

```
 public Magician()
     {
         System.out.println("Magician with " + this.lifePoints +"life points and " +this.attackPoints +" spell points.");
     }
```

Here is all the code:

Hero-

```
abstract class Hero {

    protected int lifePoints;
    protected int attackPoints;

    public abstract Hero attack(Hero other);
    public abstract int lifePoints();

}
```

Mage:

```
public class Magician extends Hero{

    static int count;

     Magician(int lifePoints, int attackPoints)
     {
        this.lifePoints = lifePoints;
        this.attackPoints = attackPoints;
        count++;
     }

     public Magician()
     {
         System.out.println("Magician with " + this.lifePoints +"life points and " +this.attackPoints +" spell points.");
     }
    @Override
    public Hero attack(Hero other) {
        if(other != null)
        {
            if(other instanceof Hero)
            {
                other.lifePoints /= this.attackPoints;
                if(other.lifePoints <= 0)
                {
                    return new Magician(this.lifePoints,this.attackPoints);
                }
            }
            //Attacking ourselves - Error
            if(this.equals(other))
            {
                System.out.println("Hero can't attack itself");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int lifePoints() {
        return this.lifePoints;
    }

    public static int getNoMagician()
    {
        return count;
    }

}
```

Warrior:

```
public class Warrior extends Hero
{
    static int count;

     Warrior(int lifePoints, int attackPoints)
     {
        this.lifePoints = lifePoints;
        this.attackPoints = attackPoints;
        count++;
     }
     public Warrior()
     {
         System.out.println("Warrior with " + this.lifePoints +"life points and " +this.attackPoints +" spell points.");
     }

    @Override
    public Hero attack(Hero other) {
        if(other != null)
        {
            //We're attacking a warrior
            if(other instanceof Warrior){
                ((Warrior)other).lifePoints -= this.attackPoints;

            }
            //We're attacking a magician
            if(other instanceof Magician){
                ((Magician)other).lifePoints -= (this.attackPoints / 2);
                if(((Magician)other).lifePoints <= (this.lifePoints / 2))
                {
                    return new Warrior(this.lifePoints,this.attackPoints);
                }

            }
            //Attacking ourselves - Error
            if(this.equals(other))
            {
                System.out.println("Hero can't attack itself");
            }
        }
        //False
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int lifePoints() {
        return this.lifePoints;
    }

    public static int getNoWarrior()
    {
        return count;
    }

}
```

Comment: That's the default string conversion for classes without a toString. Either create a toString or print things out explicitly. Each has pros and cons.

Comment: Consider overriding `toString`

Comment: @DaveNewton Works. I'm so stupid. Thanks!

Comment: @bradimus Thanks Bradimus. it has solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `toString()` of an object is what you're calling its Hashcode.  In order to get the output you want, you need to create your own method in each subclass of `Hero`, e.g. in class Magician:-

```
public String getDescription() {
    return "Magician with " + this.lifePoints +" life points and " +this.attackPoints +" spell points.");
}
```

Then call this method as follows:-

```
for (int i=0; i<heroes.size(); ++i) {
    System.out.println("Hero " + i + " is a "+heroes.get(i).getDescription());
}
```

Note that I wouldn't override `toString()` for this purpose, as this method is often used for debugging.  If someone else edits your code, they might change the toString() output, not realising that it's critical to the program's function.

UPDATE: I'm not saying that `toString()` should never be overridden, just not in this particular case where the specific text is necessary for the game.

Comment: I'm not allowed to change the main code. I just had to override the toString to return what you just wrote in getDesc func. thanks Steve

Comment: "I wouldn't override `toString()` Then you're flying in the face of established best practice. One should always override `toString` for value types, and it should embed representations of all fields involved in `equals`. The advice to avoid that is wrong.

Comment: To clarify, I meant I wouldn't override it for this particular use (which is presumably for a specific feature of the game and doesn't include all fields).  Yes, `toString()` should be overridden, but for debugging purposes as you describe.